# PythonとMySQLを接続したら、ウェブアプリが作動しなくなった

Tags: python, html, mysql

**前提・実現したいこと**
PythonとHTMLテンプレートを使用して作ったウェブアプリのログを、
MySQL上にテーブルを作って閲覧したいと思っています。

そこでPythonとMySQLを接続し、
Pythonのコードを書き替えたら、
ウェブアプリは表示されるのですが、
検索機能を実行しようとすると、
エラーが起きてしまいました...

発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'vsearch'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
該当のソースコード
変更前

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, escape
from vsearch import search4letters

app = Flask(__name__)


def log_request(req: 'flask_request', res: str) -> None:
    with open('vsearch.log', 'a') as log:
        print(req.form, req.remote_addr, req.user_agent, res, file=log, sep='|')


@app.route('/search4', methods=['POST'])
def do_search() -> 'html':
    phrase = request.form['phrase']
    letters = request.form['letters']
    title = 'Here are your results:'
    results = str(search4letters(phrase, letters))
    log_request(request, results)
    return render_template('results.html',
                           the_title=title,
                           the_phrase=phrase,
                           the_letters=letters,
                           the_results=results,)


@app.route('/')
@app.route('/entry')
def entry_page() -> 'html':
    return render_template('entry.html',
                           the_title='Welcome to search4letters on the web!')


@app.route('/viewlog')
def view_the_log() -> 'html':
    contents = []
    with open('vsearch.log') as log:
        for line in log:
            contents.append([])
            for item in line.split('|'):
                contents[-1].append(escape(item))
    titles = ('Form Data', 'Remote_addr', 'User_agent', 'Results')
    return render_template('viewlog.html',
                           the_title='View Log',
                           the_row_titles=titles,
                           the_data=contents,)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

変更後

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, escape
from vsearch import search4letters

app = Flask(__name__)

def log_request(req: 'flask_request', res: str) -> None:
    dbconfig = {'host': '127.0.0.1',
                'user': 'vsearch',
                'password': 'vsearchpasswd',
                'database': 'vsearchlogDB',}
    import mysql.connector
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(**dbconfig)
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    _SQL = """insert into log
              (phrase, letters, ip, browser_string, results)
              values
              (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""
    cursor.execute(_SQL, (req.form['phrase'],
                          req.form['letters'],
                           req.remote_addr,
                           req.user_agent.browser,
                           res,))
    conn.commit()
    curosr.close()
    conn.close()


@app.route('/search4', methods=['POST'])
def do_search() -> 'html':
    phrase = request.form['phrase']
    letters = request.form['letters']
    title = 'Here are your results:'
    results = str(search4letters(phrase, letters))
    log_request(request, results)
    return render_template('results.html',
                           the_title=title,
                           the_phrase=phrase,
                           the_letters=letters,
                           the_results=results,)


@app.route('/')
@app.route('/entry')
def entry_page() -> 'html':
    """Display this webapp's HTML form."""
    return render_template('entry.html',
                           the_title='Welcome to search4letters on the web!')


@app.route('/viewlog')
def view_the_log() -> 'html':
    """Display the contents of the log file as a HTML table."""
    contents = []
    with open('vsearch.log') as log:
        for line in log:
            contents.append([])
            for item in line.split('|'):
                contents[-1].append(escape(item))
    titles = ('Form Data', 'Remote_addr', 'User_agent', 'Results')
    return render_template('viewlog.html',
                           the_title='View Log',
                           the_row_titles=titles,
                           the_data=contents,)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

*MySQL*

```
create user '***'@'####' identified by '????';
grant all privileges on vsearchlogDB.* to '***'@'####';
```

**試したこと**
[参考にしたページ][1]
アクセスが拒否されたとき
上のウェブサイトを参考に
復旧を試みましたが
ダメでした....

補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）
Python 3.7 (64 bit)
MySQL 8.0
使用教材　『Head First Python』O'Reilly Japan

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: マルチポスト - https://teratail.com/questions/195839

Comment: エラー内容的にMySQLの接続エラーのようです。pythonからではなく、直接コンソールから該当の認証情報でMySQLの接続を試してもらってその内容を追記シていただけると幸いです。